# Set max length on string variable

Tags: azure, ansible, jinja2

I am using Ansible to create an Azure storage account which must have a max name size of 24 characters. I am looking at the Jinja `truncate()` method but the parameter passed to this method removes that number of characters rather than limiting the string to that number of characters.

Is there a different way of implementing a max length of string variable?
Do I need to combine `truncate` and `length` filters from Jinja?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Python's slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2123530) for this.

> Slice objects are also generated when extended indexing syntax is used. For example: `a[start:stop:step]` or `a[start:stop, i]`.

<sup>*More in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice*</sup>
<sup>*Also a good read: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html*</sup>

Given:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ str[:24] }}"
  vars:
    str: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

This should give you:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
```